# How to push data down if it will be overwritten from an arrayformula function

Tags: google-sheets

I have 3 tabs in a google sheet, and need to combine then on one tab.

However, they will grow rows wise and I need them to be able to push other tables down.

ArrayFormula works, but it doesn't push data down when it's in the way.
This is the error :

> "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in
> A13."

Is there a way to push data down, or make the formula dynamic?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to combine the 3 tabs using just one formula try something like this:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!A2:G;Sheet2!A2:G;Sheet3!A2:G},"where Col1 is not null",0)
```

Comment: This is almost what I need, but what happens if I have different table col sizes? I could add place holder columns to make them all the same, but that would look terrible.

Comment: ArrayFormula merged with this allowed me to create empty cols.
=Query(ArrayFormula(iferror({open_pos_pivot!A4:D,{" "," "," "," "," "," "}/row(open_pos_pivot!A4:A),open_pos_pivot!E4:BU

plus whatever other tables I had.